# Create and update data same time in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a report management system. I want to sum up a certain amount of data by fiscal year, month, and report type. I have used the below queries to fetch the data:

```
$data['reports'] = Report::distric()
->where('fiscal_year', $request->fiscalyear)
->where('month', $request->month)
->where('report_type', $request->report_type)
->status(1)
->get();
```

The columns on my table look like this:

```
| column_one | column_two | report_id |
```

I was also able, to sum up, the specific reports. This is my view code:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($reports as $data)
<tr>
<td class="numeric_bangla">{{$data->column_one}}</td>
<td class="numeric_bangla">{{$data->column_two}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach

<tr class="text-purple">
<td style="font-weight:bold;">Total</td>
<td class="numeric_bangla" style="font-weight:bold;">{{ $reports->sum('column_one') }}</td>
<td class="numeric_bangla" style="font-weight:bold;">{{ $reports->sum('column_two') }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

But I mean, I want my summed data to be stored separately in the database, and the ID of the newly created report will sit in a column in a table of data that I've summed up. How can I do this now?

This is my full controller code:

```
public function InitialCreateReport(Request $request)
{
$request->session()->forget('report');
$data['fiscalyear'] = FiscalYear::all();
$data['month'] = Months::all();
$data['report_type'] = ReportType::all();
$data['report'] = $request->session()->get('report');
return view('adc.reports.create-report', $data);
}

public function PostInitialCreateReport(Request $request)
{
$validatedData = $request->validate([
'fiscalyear' => 'required',
'month' => 'required',
'report_type' => 'required',
]);

if (empty($request->session()->get('report'))) {
$report = new Report();
$report->fill($validatedData);
$request->session()->put('report', $report);
} else {
$report = $request->session()->get('report');
$report->fill($validatedData);
$report->session()->put('report', $report);
}

$data['reports'] = Report::distric()
->where('fiscal_year', $request->fiscalyear)
->where('month', $request->month)
->where('report_type', $request->report_type)
->status(1)
->get();
return view('adc.reports.start-create-report', $data);
}

public function PostCreateRentCertificateReport(Request $request)
{
$report = $request->session()->get('report');
$request->session()->put('report', $report);
$report = $request->session()->get('report');
return view('adc.reports.preview-rent-certificate-report', compact('report', $report));
}

public function PostPreviewRentCertificateReport(Request $request)
{
$report = $request->session()->get('report');
return view('adc.reports.save-rent-certificate-report', compact('report', $report));
}

public function PostSaveRentCertificateReport(Request $request)
{
$report = $request->session()->get('report');
$reports = new Report;
$reports->column_one = $report->sum('column_one');
$reports->column_two = $report->sum('column_two');

//I want to put the ID of my newly created report in those reports.

$reports->save();
$notification = array(
'message' => 'Report Created Successfully',
'alert-type' => 'success'
);
return redirect()->route('adc.pending.reports')->with($notification);
}
```

How can I do this on one table?

Comment: If you want to pass newly created report id in other reports then you should have filter data or reportIds or whatever info that can tell you those reports needs update.

Comment: @InsaneSkull, Sir Please can you show me how can I do that? I'm very new so I can't understand.

Comment: Add sample data how should your db should look like after saving new report.